# Javascript Function doesnt work when adding a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a working JavaScript function that's supposed to upload a file, but when trying to add the other inputs (like title or description, but not the file!) to a variable, it doesn't work anymore completely and I absolutely dont know why. So uploading a file works, but when I try to get the information of other fields it doesn't work..

Here is the JavaScript Function:

```
function uploadFile()
{
    //Wieder unser File Objekt
    var file = document.getElementById("fileA").files[0];
    //FormData Objekt erzeugen
    var formData = new FormData();
    //XMLHttpRequest Objekt erzeugen
       client = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var prog = document.getElementById("progress");

    if(!file)
        return;
    if ((file.type !=='video/mp4')&&(file.type !=='video/mpeg')&&(file.type !=='video/avi')&&(file.type !=='video/wmv')&&(file.type !=='video/mov')&&(file.type !=='video/mkv')&&(file.type !=='video/flv')) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'Datei ist in keinem unterstützes Videoformat';
        return;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = '';
    }

    prog.value = 0;
    prog.max = 100;

    //Alle anderen Werte bekommen

    //Fügt dem formData Objekt unser File Objekt hinzu
    formData.append("datei", file);

    client.onerror = function(e) {
        alert("onError");
    };

    client.onload = function(e) {
        document.getElementById("prozent").innerHTML = "100%";
        prog.value = prog.max;
    };

    client.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        var p = Math.round(100 / e.total * e.loaded);
        document.getElementById("progress").value = p;
        document.getElementById("progress").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("prozent").innerHTML = p + "%";
         document.getElementById("prozent").style.display = 'block';
    };

    client.onabort = function(e) {
        alert("Upload abgebrochen");
    };

    client.open("POST", "index.php");
    client.send(formData);
}
```

I've tried to add the following to many different lines, but even when not doing anything with the variable the function doesn't work anymore:

```
var formvalues = $('#script_uploader').serialize();
```

Does JavaScript stop the script or somewhat like that if the id "script_uploader" isn't found? But my form has that ID!

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="script_uploader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br/>Titel: <input name="title" type="text" size="40" />
<br/>Gewicht: 
<select name="weight">
    <option>-120</option>
</select>
<br/>Länge: <input name="length" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Gib die Länge des Videos in Minuten ein"/>
 <input name="file" type="file" id="fileA" onchange="fileChange();"/>
 <progress id="progress" class="bar" style="margin-top:10px" value="0"></progress> <span id="prozent"></span>
<br/><input name="upload" value="Upload" type="button" onclick="uploadFile();" />
<input name="abort" value="Abbrechen" type="button" onclick="uploadAbort();" />
```

Comment: I will ask the obvious question.  Do you have the jQuery library included in your page?  The `$` in `$('#script_uploader').serialize();` is probably meant to be jQuery.  Also, you should look in the browser error console or debug console to see what errors it is reporting for your script and it will tell you exactly why it is stopping the execution.

Comment: Are the variables `formvalues` and `formData` supposed to be the same? You `append` to `formData`, but serialize into `formvalues`. At least so it appears.

Comment: okay, i'm sorry that i have forgotten the obvious. i forgot to include the jquery library^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CITdAIfkukjm70oozsfL?p=preview

do you connect jQuery on your page? 
So you have no element with the id "message".

Or you can use this approach to send all data in POST variables:
http://plnkr.co/edit/RseFjebCDOGmWEIxhpTF?p=preview

Comment: So you have a method not implemented "onchange="fileChange();" which is present in the HTML file input.